# Tracking "Windows Search" Queries

Tags: windows-search, data-tracing

I can enable logging for *Windows Search* through the registry (see below), but this only captures queries sent through the default user-interface for *Windows Search*. I want to capture queries used by *Outlook 2003*, *Outlook 2007*, *OneNote 2007* or any other application that accesses the `SystemIndex`.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Desktop Search\DS\WriteLog[DWORD]0|1
```

What I want to do is analyze these queries in order get a better understanding on how to build queries for my personal search utility (WinForms/WPF/ADO.NET/OleDb) that I use to search my code library (physical file system).

How would I track any and all queries performed on the SystemIndex of *Windows Search*?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to capture all accesses to the SystemIndex, that would be quite the tall order, as there are [multiple ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266517(VS.85).aspx) it can be accessed:

- [Using SQL and AQS Approaches to Query
  the Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff684395(VS.85).aspx)
- [Querying the Index with
  ISearchQueryHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266518(VS.85).aspx)
- [Querying the Index with the search-ms
  Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266520(VS.85).aspx)
- [Querying the Index with Windows
  Search SQL Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231256(VS.85).aspx)
- [Using Advanced Query Syntax
  Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512(VS.85).aspx)

If we ignore that for a bit and focus on your other goal:

> What I want to do is analyze these queries in order get a
> better understanding on how to build
> queries for my personal search utility

Then I would look into the [ISearchQueryHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231313(VS.85).aspx) Interface.

> **ISearchQueryHelper Interface**
>
> Provides methods for building a query
> from user input, converting a query to
> Windows Search SQL, and obtaining a
> connection string to initialize a
> connection to the Window Search index.

One method of that interface is [GenerateSQLFromUserQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231302(VS.85).aspx), which may help you out.

> **GenerateSQLFromUserQuery**
>
> Generates a Structured Query Language (SQL)
> query based on a client-supplied query
> string expressed in either Advanced
> Query Syntax (AQS) or Natural Query
> Syntax (NQS).

Comment: I already use and understand the interface and method. There must be a way to capture the queries against the index. Regardless of the multiple ways of capturing the user's query, I believe everything is converted into a SELECT statement at the lowest level. I want to capture these SELECT statements.

Comment: You could try finding the DLL that implements the ISearchQueryHelper and/or the methods of interest and create a wrapper around it, so every process that uses it will load you instead, and then you just log the requests and pass the request to the real dll...

Answer (score 0):

The system index is implemented as an OLE DB source. You can find out the data source from the connection string provided by [ISearchQueryHelper::get_ConnectionString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231303%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I've been looking for a way to monitor an OLE DB source, but turned up nothing so far.

The OLE DB boils down to the [Extensible Storage Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine) (ESE) file named `Windows.edb` that exists, by default, in the `\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\` profile folder.

All ESE files are managed by ESENT.DLL. It may be possible to hook this DLL and trace queries. Hooking and logging is possible with programs such as with [StraceNT](http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=strace.htm), and [xptruss](http://dev.depeuter.org/xptruss.php)

After a couple of hours searching, there doesn't appear to be any simpler way to get a log of all Windows Search queries. Since learning the query syntax is your goal, it may be simpler to look elsewhere for learning aids, such as using the default Windows Search UI and using the query log that you know about already. It may also be helpful to experiement with converting ADS and NDS queries to SQL using the `ISearchQueryHelper` interface.

Comment: "helpful to experiment": I have and been able to adjust my queries to better duplicate the results of "Indexing Service" results.

Comment: I have been able to duplicate the default Windows Search UI queries by reviewing the log generated when `WriteLog` is set. It is generic and retrieves too many unneeded properties, such as picture, music, and other "silly" properties that I do not need for "code searching". I want to see how *Outlook* and *OneNote* handle the queries because these applications would perform "specific" queries. I want to create queries that can search "code" effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is here, but have not had time to try it out.

- Troubleshooting Windows DAC/MDAC
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693114(VS.85).aspx
- Data Access Tracing in SQL Server 2008
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421.aspx